# Change button color in Tailwind/TypeScript when button is Active

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a Carousel Object which contains Buttons. These buttons represent the "Semester" content shown below (an image is provided below).

[image]

I want the "semester 1" button to be Dark Blue by default and when another button is clicked I want that button to be Dark Blue.

At the moment I can achieve this when I add the following `focus:`  class to the Button Component but since it's a focus class it turns light blue the moment I click somewhere else and the button "semester 1" is not dark blue by default:

`class="rounded-full w-64 dark:bg-blue-300 dark:hover:bg-blue-500 focus:bg-blue-500"`

[image]

I tried adding an `class="active:bg-blue-500"` but was unsuccessful.
Why doesn't adding an `active` class work, and how can I make this work?

Comment: How do you managed the change of the view when a button is clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo class `active` is corresponding to when the user has an interaction with an element (in this case, when the user is clicking on the button), but once the interaction is over the pseudo class won't be active.

What you want cannot be done with only css, you need some javascript to add a stlye or a class to the button you clicked on (and remove those class / style on the last clicked button)

For example if you are in vanilla js and you have three buttons with the class "navigation-buttons", what can do what you want is to add a class 'active' when one is clicked.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-buttons')
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Remove active class on all buttons
    buttons.forEach((b) => b.classList.remove('active')
    // Add active on the one clicked
    button.classList.add('active')
  });
});
```

Comment: With this approach, he has to write his own CSS for the `.active` state, while he already uses Tailwind to avoid writing common CSS. Also, his buttons have already `bg-blue-300` and you apply another class that will probably have the `background-color` of `bg-blue-500`, so the clicked button will effectively have **two** background-colors which is bad tactic (even though it works).

Comment: It is not uncommon to overwrite a css property with another. Also we can define custom classes in tailwind, but if all he wants is to change the background-color he can use `bg-blue-500`. I just provided a working example

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind's `active` is about the CSS pseudo [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) state and this is different from what you expect as an active button in your situation. For example, in plain JS:

```js
const defaultColor = 'bg-blue-300'; // Default color
const activeColor = 'bg-blue-500'; // Active color
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'); // Select all buttons

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Rest all button colors
    buttons.forEach((b) => {
      b.classList.add(defaultColor);
      b.classList.remove(activeColor);
    });
    // Add active color on the clicked button, remove default color
    btn.classList.remove(defaultColor);
    btn.classList.add(activeColor);
  });
});
```

```css
/*Used as Tailwind Library*/

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.gap-2 {
  gap: 8px;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  background: rgb(147 197 253);
}

.bg-blue-500 {
  background: rgb(59 130 246);
}

.text-white {
  color: rgb(255 255 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex gap-2">
  <button class="btn text-white bg-blue-300">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn text-white bg-blue-300">Button 2</button>
  <button class="btn text-white bg-blue-300">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

If you are using React, you'll have to use a `useState` to store which button is active:

```js
const Buttons = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('b1'); // b1 = button1, b2 = button2, etc...
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2">
      <button
        className={`rounded-full w-64 ${active === 'b1' ? 'bg-blue-500' : 'bg-blue-300'}`}
        onClick={() => setActive('b1')}
      >Button 1</button>
      <button
        className={`rounded-full w-64 ${active === 'b2' ? 'bg-blue-500' : 'bg-blue-300'}`}
        onClick={() => setActive('b2')}
      >Button 2</button>
      <button
        className={`rounded-full w-64 ${active === 'b3' ? 'bg-blue-500' : 'bg-blue-300'}`}
        onClick={() => setActive('b3')}
      >Button 3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: He never said he was using React