# How do I change button color to show visitor is on current page in reactJS with react router?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to make the button to change background color to let the visitor know which page they are currently on. Anyone know how to do that? I've only managed to make it change color upon clicking

Comment: Are you referring to react routing or just URL hash/path resolution? Is it a SAP (single-page application)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change button color in Tailwind/TypeScript when button is Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660773/change-button-color-in-tailwind-typescript-when-button-is-active)

Comment: This is too broad of a question, do you mean have a certain color for certain pages? Or change to a different color when you switch pages? Are they randomized colors or not?

Comment: sorry i meant react routing and not randomized color

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`react-router`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router) or write your own custom routing handler logic.

**Update:** If you are using `react-router`, you can use the `useLocation` hook.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

#### Custom routing example

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState('');

  const handleHashChange = useCallback(({ target: { location: { hash } } }) => {
    setPage(hash.replace(/^#/, ''));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange, false);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li className={page === 'home' || page === '' ? 'active' : ''}>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li className={page === 'about' ? 'active' : ''}>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```